# Ng Select (scrollToEnd) emits the event only once

Tags: angular, web, frontend, web-frontend, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select version 9.0.1. The (scrollToEnd) emits the event only once.

```
<ng-select (scrollToEnd)="test($event)" [virtualScroll]="true" [items]="usersList" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id"></ng-select>
```

I am loading certain number of items when the scrollbar reaches to end

```
 test(e) {
    console.log('Event', e)
    console.log(this.usersList)
    for (let index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
      this.usersList = [...this.usersList, {id: 1, name: 'New item'+index}];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Once opened, it only emits once. It emits again on reopening

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it emits again while on reopening.

Comment: I think that's the intended behavior by the ng-select team

Comment: The `items` binding should be a new reference to make `scrollToEnd` fire, which is true in this case so I'm not sure what's the problem, did you use the same data you post here? If you can, create a stackblitz and share here so everyone can debug it.